# Add extra params to $cordovaFileTransfer.upload

Tags: angularjs, upload, ionic-framework, file-transfer, ngcordova

I am using `$cordovaFileTransfer.upload()` to upload a picture from a device to my server. In documentation it says that it excepts these params: `server, filePath, options`. I need to pass in some extra custom params: like `user_id`, for example. Does anyone know if it's possible to do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can send those custom parameters in the options object, doing something like this:

```
var options = {};
options.headers = {
    Connection: "close"
}
options.chunkedMode = false;
options.userName = 'Mati';

$cordovaFileTransfer.upload(server, filePath, options)
```

Comment: It seems like these options build a specific request header. (I use django). I wasn't able to find my params inside...

Comment: @chabislav they are sent as a POST. Try to dump the whole POST request

Comment: @chabislav try adding this: 
`options.headers = {
    Connection: "close"
}
options.chunkedMode = false;
`

Answer (score 0):

You can add "params" to options object, 
for example :

```
 var options = {
                fileKey: "name",
                fileName: "image.png",
                chunkedMode: false,
                mimeType: "image/png",
                httpMethod: "post",  //here the methed (get, post,..) 
                params: $scope.Data  //here you can submit the data
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the 'params' property, like this:

```
var _options = {
    fileKey: "image_name",
    fileName: "image.jpg",
    chunkedMode: false,
    mimeType: "image/jpeg",
    httpMethod: "POST",
    headers: { },
    params: {
        "extra_param_name": "Jamilson",
        "extra_param_last_name": "Junior"
    }
};
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "image";
options.fileName="image.jpg";
options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
options.httpMethod="POST";
options.headers = {
    Connection: "close"
};
options.chunkedMode = false;
var params = {};
params.user_id ="123";
params.username="username";
options.params = params;
```