# ionic3 change cropped image to base64 string

Tags: typescript, base64, ionic3

I am using ionic3 native crop image plugin, and it works and have a src image path, but I need to change it to a base64 string for sending it to the server. How to change it, here is my code for crop image, thanks a lot.

```
        console.log('buttonCamera clicked');
        let cameraOptions = {
          sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
          destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,      
          quality: 100,
          targetWidth: 500,
          targetHeight: 500,
          encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,      
          correctOrientation: true
        }

        this.camera.getPicture(cameraOptions)
        .then(file_uri => {
           this.crop.crop(file_uri, {quality: 100})
           .then(
              newImage => {console.log('new image path is: ' + newImage);
              this.imageSrc = newImage},
              error => console.error('Error cropping image', error)
           );
        },
        err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: why not use FileTransfer Ionic native plugin to send as url?

Comment: Because i have other params need to send together in one api

Comment: you can use params check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618984/add-extra-params-to-cordovafiletransfer-upload

Comment: hi suraj, thanks for your reply, so that no way to change a image to base64 string?

Comment: you can get image data initially by setting `this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URI` but in your case based on your question I think the linked answer is better..

Comment: hi suraj, when i try to change the destination type, i have the following error:
Typescript Error
Property 'DATA_URI' does not exist on type '{ DATA_URL: number; FILE_URI: number; NATIVE_URI: number; }'.

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/ I guess it is DATA_URL

Answer (score 0):

In **Ionic 4** use **file** native plugin to call **readAsDataURL**

```
  showCroppedImage(ImagePath){
    this.isLoading = true;
    var copyPath = ImagePath;
    var splitPath = copyPath.split('/');
    var imageName = splitPath[splitPath.length-1];
    var filePath = ImagePath.split(imageName)[0];

    this.file.readAsDataURL(filePath,imageName).then(base64=>{
        this.croppedImagepath = base64;
        this.isLoading = false;
    },error=>{
      alert('Error in showing image' + error);
      this.isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

Check full tutorial [here](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-crop-images-selected-from-image-selector-show-in-base64-format-using-native-plugins/)

Answer (score -1):

Just make small change in cameraOption:

```
destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
```

And it is done!